# Can non-constant functions have the IVP and have local extremum everywhere?

Tags: analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ has Intermediate value property. If f has local extremum at every point of $\mathbb R$, can we say f is constant?
We know $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 & x \in \Bbb{Q} \\ 0 & x \not \in \Bbb{Q}\end{cases}$$ has I.V.P and every point of $\mathbb R$ is local extremum but f is not constant.
We know **If f is continuous and have local extremum at every point then we can conclude f is constant**
if all extremum are maximum or minimum then proof is easy and is as follow:

If f is continuous and has a local maximum everywhere, then, let $a \in \mathbb R$. By continuity, $\{x:f(x)≤f(a)\}$ is closed, and by the hypothesis, $\{x:f(x)≤f(a)\}$ is open. The set $\{x:f(x)≤f(a)\}$ is nonempty, open and closed set of $\mathbb R$ so it is all of $\mathbb R$ by connectedness of $\mathbb R$. Therefore, for all $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb R$, $f(b)≤f(a)$ and similarly $f(a)≤f(b)$.

Comment: Your $f$ does not satisfy IVP.

Comment: What do you mean by local extremum at every point of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: both kind , local maximum or local minimum .

Comment: @masoud I believe they are defined in an interval rather than at a point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Lemma:** For any function $f$ on $\mathbb R$, there are at most countably many values $y$ such that for some local extremum $x$ of $f$, $f(x) = y$.

Proof: For each local maximum $x$, take an interval $I(x)$ with rational endpoints that contains $x$, such that $f(x) = \sup \{f(t): t \in I(x)\}$.
There are only countably many intervals with rational endpoints, and if $I(x_1) = I(x_2)$ then $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$.  Similarly for local minimum.

**Corollary:** A function $f$ that has a local extremum at every point of $\mathbb R$ takes only countably many values.  In particular, it can't have the IVP unless it is constant.